# mousemove event doesnt work on ads in chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i was testing my extension and i thought everything is fine until i moved my mouse cursor on an ad in stackoverflow and w3school and some other websites!
my mousemove event doesnt work on ads. i dont know why.
my event handler is:

```
window.handler = window.handler || function (e) {
  console.log("on");

  document.querySelectorAll(".x_place_ext")[
    document.querySelectorAll(".x_place_ext").length - 1
  ].textContent = e.clientX;

  document.querySelectorAll(".y_place_ext")[
    document.querySelectorAll(".y_place_ext").length - 1
  ].textContent = e.clientY;
};

let positions = document.querySelectorAll("#positions_container_ext");
positions = positions[positions.length - 1];

document
  .querySelector("html")
  .addEventListener("mousemove", window.handler);
```

i have no idea why these codes dont work on ads in websites.
can you halp me?

Comment: Mouse events don't work over iframes. You need to run a content script inside iframes by setting [all_frames](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#frames) in manifest.json or [allFrames](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-InjectionTarget) in executeScript.

Comment: hello. thank you for your help and it worked. but here i have a problem. when i set mousemove event on all iframes, i'll get clientX and clientY of its iframe. what can i do to get the clientX and clientY of the main page not the iframe?

Comment: It's complicated for cross-origin iframes. Maybe you can use e.screenX/Y instead?

Comment: i cant. because screenX/Y is for the users screen! it means that if user moves the mouse curser to the left corner of its current website, the Y wont be 0 because screenY/X is exactly for the users device screen. i want to get the position of the website. do you have other solution for this?